# Sending jquery variable data to php in the same file

Tags: php, jquery

so i've got some problems. This is also my first post here on stackoverflow so I might make some errors :) But this is my code and I do belive I have made some big error but I can't really figure it out. So basiclly what I want it to do is to send the word that is marked with italic letters to the php in the same file and then the php should send it back so the jquery can use it and display the tooltip. But im having problems even getting the word sent to the php. I would be very happy if someone could solve this, Thanks! And btw the file everything is written in is called tooltip.php

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['ord'])){ echo $_POST['ord']; }

?>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde <i>mupp</i> iste natus error sit
<i>hej</i>voluptatem accusantiumdoloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam
<i>eaque</i> ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatiset
quasi architecto beatae <i>hej</i> dicta sunt <i>html</i>, och <i>CSS</i></p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function($){
        $.fn.qtip = function(options){
    return this.each(function(){
            var x, y, ex, el = $(this);
            el.on({
         mouseenter: function(e){

           ex = $('<div id="qtip"></div');           
           el.append(ex);


           var tx = el.text() ;



               $.post( 'tooltip.php', {ord: tx} function( data ) {

              if(!data)
                data = <?php echo json_encode($testvar); ?>;

                    ex.html( <?php echo json_encode($testvar); ?> );

                });





           var os = el.offset();
           y = os.top + el.height();
           x = os.left;

           ex.offset({top: y, left: x});
           ex.css('font-size', '0.9em');
         },
         mouseleave: function(e){    
            ex.remove();   
         }
        });
    });
    };
    }(jQuery));

 $('i').qtip();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `data = <?php echo json_encode($testvar); ?>` should be `data = "<?php echo json_encode($testvar); ?>"` and for similar

Comment: @FrayneKonok No, I don't think it should. That would make it a string, not an object.

Comment: I don't have vast knowledge about jquery or ajax. I know little bit PHP.

Answer (score 0):

couple of things, $testvar is undefined. it is a php var, and your not setting that anywhere prior to asking for it in JS.

also, in the $.post, your asking for a reply from that same page...which will be all the html, but im guessing your only wanting some part of it.

basically, you possibly need more php (if youre set on having it all on the same php page.)

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST)){
    print_r($_POST);
    die();
  }else{
    //now render the page since it was not posted to
?>
your html and js
...
...
<?php }?>
```

this shoud return the posted value (assuming your js is correct) back to the jquery callback.  so see if it was successful, you will have to view it using js, not php.

something like

```
$.post( 'tooltip.php', {ord: tx} function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
```

not a complete answer, but hopefully get you in the right direction